# Change particular values in DAO/Repository when reading entities

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I am reading data from old legacy dabatase. Somehow, they place all non-existing relationship using 0 index, for example:
Object Person:

```
id: 123
name: john
surname: snow
birthCityId: 0 <-- this means that there is no relationship between city and this person.
```

Now, in JPA I have the problem that it is loading person entity but it cannot find related city entity with index 0. I would like to code that when I have city with ID 0, then City entity is set to null.
How can I do that?
I don't want to create a new entity with index 0 into the db.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Hibernate `@NotFound` annotation:

```
@ManyToOne
@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private City birthCity;
```

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.3/javadocs/index.html?org/hibernate/annotations/NotFound.html

I do not see the other posted solutions working as an exception will occur on Hibernate load i.e. prior to you being able to handle it by other means.

Comment: Thanks :) This worked out well for me. I also combined it with @Comfort Chauke solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am asuming u have

```
Person{
@Many2One @JoinColumn("birthCityId") City birthCity;
...}
```

the easiest solution is to add table row with id=0 in city and the rest be nulls

and this to your class

```
@PostLoad
public viod cityInit(){
   if(birthCity!=null&&birthCity.getId()==0){
      birthCity==null;
   }
}
```

There are more elegant solutions but this will get you started quickly

Comment: I like this solution, but I would not make db dirty with inconsistent entries. Is there any other way to solve it without add a row with id=0? I tried with Lazyload but it doesn't work.

Comment: You are right, its a dirty solution, but the db is already dirty that is why there is no JPA solution. Clean solution is to replace 0 with null and create a foreign key on field person.birthCityId to city.id.

Using @NotFound is not clean too because its implementation specific, changing JPA implementation will break your code!